# How to retrieve Sabre profile using SOAP API

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm trying to use the Sabre SOAP API to retrieve a profile. I'm using the SOAP template here (https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/soap-apis-request-format) with the specifics here (https://developer.sabre.com/sabre_hospitality/apis/soap_apis/hotel/profile/read_profile). I'm able to get a BinarySession token ok using the SessionCreateRQ request ok. It starts with the text "Shared/IDL:IceSess/SessMgr".

My request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId />
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId />
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>ipcc</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>conversationID</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>OTA_ReadRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_ReadRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">MY SECURITY TOKEN GOES HERE</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <eb:SoapAPIServiceActionCode>
      <OTA_ReadRQ Version="1" EchoToken="1122" PrimaryLangID="en" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <ReadRequests>
      <ProfileReadRequest>
          <UniqueID Type="1" ID="14EF985B2C" ID_Context="crs">
              <CompanyName CodeContext="hotel" Code="10001"/>
          </UniqueID>
      </ProfileReadRequest>
  </ReadRequests>
</OTA_ReadRQ>
    </eb:SoapAPIServiceActionCode>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But when I do this I get the error:

```
    <soap-env:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidAction</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.xml.USG_INVALID_ACTION</StackTrace>
        </detail>
    </soap-env:Fault>
```

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<eb:Action>OTA_ProfileReadRQ</eb:Action>` instead.

Sabre responds with `OTA_ProfileReadRS`, so I suppose the Action code may contain "ProfileRead" as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have permission in your iPCC/EPR the authorization to use this service.

The faultstring="***Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.***" error was in <eb:Action>***OTA_ReadRQ***</eb:Action>.
You can read more details about the hospitallity services in:

- https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/get-hotel-avail-v2-sample-nodejs
- https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/get-hotel-details-sample-nodejs
- https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/hotel-price-check-v2-sample-nodejs